# Introductory Proof Help

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I am very new to proofs, and I would like to make sure that I am doing them correctly. I am attempting to learn them outside of class, so any comments about proof style or general logical thinking processes would be greatly appreciated! Sorry for the poor formatting as well, I was having some difficulties transferring this proof in a more readable manner.

Proof

For every integer x, if x is odd, then there exists an integer y such that x^2 = 8y+1.

Let x be an odd integer and y be arbitrary.

```
x = 2y+1
```

This implies that

```
x^2 = (2y+1)^2

x^2 = 4y^2+4y+1.
```

If x^2 = 8y+1 then,

```
8y+1 = 4y^2+4y+1.

0 = 4y^2-4y

0 = 4y(y-1)

y = 1, y = 0
```

This implies that there exists an integer y in the set of all integers such that x^2=8y+1.

Q.E.D

Comment: Here's how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You are using the **same** letter $y$ for two **different** things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume what you are trying to prove, so the step $8y+1 = 4y^2+4y+1$ is invalid. Furthermore, you are confusing the $y$ that you defined and the $y$ in the question, which are two different things.

Instead, think about what happens if $m$ (the '$y$' you defined) is odd or even since all integers must be either odd or even. This means you can either have $m=2n$ or $m=2n+1$. After substituting this into $x^2 = 4m^2+4m+1$, try to group the terms so that you have your result in the form $8(\text{something}) + 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer was very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, no problem.